# Integration by parts 2

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Say $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. $\int_0^2 F(x)dx = 3$, $\int_0^2 f(x)dx = 4$, $f(2) = 9$, $f(0) = 5$ and $F(2)=14$, and $F(0)=10$. Then $\int_0^2 f(x) x dx$ equals?

With integration by parts, I get $x*f(x) - \int_0^2 f(x)dx= [x*f(x) - 4]_0^2$ which equals $(2*f(2) - 4)-(0*f(0)-4) = 2(9) - 4 + 4 = 18$

Comment: Integrate by part.

Comment: Have you learned integration by parts yet?

Comment: I haven't, this is an advanced problem for this homework set. I think integration by parts is taught next week. I will read ahead now to attempt to answer it. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Gave it a shot, did I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** No. Try integration by parts.